# How do I pass swift CLlocation latitude and longitude to wkwebview ajax function or controller function

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

i have the location already in my view controller with my webview. How do i pass the latitude and longitude in the background to a function on the website in the wkwebview? Is there a way to pass the variables to an ajax function i have on the website?

Comment: Having Latitude and Longitude using WebView ? or using CLLocation ?

Comment: The website gets latitude and longitude but i also want the app to pass the latitude and longitude to the controller so that i can update the database in the background

Comment: You just need to get the location in background using CLLocationManager and Update the location in DB

Comment: is there anyway to do it using ajax. because i need to use the current user which is already in the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using `evaluateJavascript: completionHandler`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=objc